# NSToolbar default items

Tags: nstoolbar

Interface Builder now lets you create NSToolbar.
If this is in a Window you can set the default items by dragging to the toolbar.

If it is a different NIB this does not seem to be possible.

I have a NSToolbar in a NIB which contains a View and its controller (so that it is easy to connect to the action methods). There seems to be no way to view the toolbar, and thus set the defaults.

I do not want this toolbar to be customisable, but need to set the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 ways to change defaults:-

1. Drag toolbar into a Window, then drab back after editing.
   Unfortunately this means you have to re-connect all the action methods.
2. Edit the defaults setting in XIB file in a text editor.

In the end I moved the toolbar into the Main Window, connected the action methods to the Window Controller, which passed them on to the View.